# hi I have developed a web application using .net mvc and WebAPI as follows:

Tags: iis, publish

I have developed a web application using .net mvc and WebAPI as follows:

```
SOLUTION
  |—— WEB.API Project  
  |—— Web Application Project
```

wanting to deploy to my web server. It is possible to deploy both projects on a single web site (in iis)?

Do I need to create two separate sites for the web application and web api (in iis)?

Answer (score 0):

[image]Deploy your mvc web app as an web site & add a virtual directory under that web site & point your web api. This is the way to use 2 application under an web site.